# Database_Exception [ 1146 ]: Table 'kohana.userdetailses' doesn't exist

Tags: php, kohana

This is my Controller

userdetails.php

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Userdetails extends Controller {

    public function action_index() {
        $view = new View('userdetails/index');
        $this->response->body($view);
    }
     public function action_add() {
        $userdetails = new Model_Userdetails();         
        $view = new View('userdetails/adddetails');
        $view->set("userdetails", $userdetails);         
        $this->response->body($view);
    }
```

model is

userdetails.php

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Model_Userdetails extends ORM {

}
```

userinfo.sql

```
CREATE TABLE `kohana`.`userinfo` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I am newly learning php and kohana.I am using kohana 3.2 version.I am following [this tutorial](http://kowsercse.com/2011/09/04/kohana-tutorial-beginners/) to create,edit,update and delete data in database.I tried with above code,i am getting this error

```
"Database_Exception [ 1146 ]: Table 'kohana.userdetailses' doesn't exist [ SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `userdetailses` ]"
```

need some help to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kohana guesses the table name if `$_table_name` is not set. It pluralizes the model name as most of the time a model describes a single object, and the table describes a lot of them.

**EDIT**:

I saw you actually named your table `userinfo` and the model `userdetails`. If that is what you want:

```
class Model_Userdetails {

    protected $_table_name = 'userinfo';

    ........
}
```

Or alternatively rename the model to `Model_Userinfo`, or the table to `userdetails` and:

--- **END EDIT** ---

In your case it would seem most appropiate to:

```
class Model_Userdetails {

    protected $_table_name = 'userdetails';

    ........
}
```

Offcourse, you could alternatively rename your class to `Model_Userdetail` so that the table name will be guessed as `userdetails`

**UPDATE**:

Even though Kohana *should* guess these as well (i.e. `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FOR table` or sth), this *might* resolve the `property not found` error as discussed below in the comments.

```
protected $_table_columns = array(
    'id'        => array('type' => 'int'),
    'firstname' => array('type' => 'string'),
    ....... // repeat for all columns
);
```

Update:

There is a typo in your PHP code: `deScription`. Anyway, it is a good habit to define the table columns as this will save you an extra query every time a model is initialized for the first time. Along with some validation stuff which can take parameters from the array (e.g. the `description` of type `TEXT` is more or less not restricted in length, but **you** might want to limit it to say 2000 characters)

Comment: I added protected $_table_name = 'userinfo'; in model and the error i mentioned was solved,but again i am doing some thing wrong now i am getting this error "Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: The decription property does not exist in the Model_Userdetails class".Any idea what could be the problem.

Comment: Yes, you should also define the `$_table_columns` property, I will update the answer. There is a typo in your PHP: `deScription`